# Can apparent depth be equal to real depth in any case?

Tags: optics, refraction

Also does the depth of a tank decrease or remain same when viewed normally from above

Answer (score 0):

Apparent depth is less than the real depth and it also decreases when viewed from above.

[image]

image courtesy of [this](https://www.aplustopper.com/apparent-depth-real-depth-related-refractive-index/) website

Answer (score 0):

apparent depth=real depth/refractive index
So, for apparent depth=real depth, you need refractive index=1(vaccum or can be considered to an extent air)